# Как обратиться к *m[]?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Задача стоит реализовать функцию, которая принимает на вход двумерный массив целых чисел, ищет в этом массиве строку, содержащую наименьшее среди всех элементов массива значение, и меняет эту строку местами с первой строкой массива.

Также рекомендуется обменять строки массива, не обменивая элементы строк по-отдельности.

Не могу понять как обратиться к *m[] ? Это массив указателей или указатель на массивы?

Спасибо!

```
void swap_min(int *m[], unsigned rows, unsigned cols){
    int row_with_min = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i != rows ; i++ ){
        for ( int j = 0; j != cols ; j++ ){
                if (m[i][j] < min){
                    row_with_min = i;
                    cout << i << endl;
                }
                //... Как здесь с помощью указателей поменять строки местами?...//
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша функция объявлена как

```
void swap_min(int *m[], unsigned rows, unsigned cols);
```

Ее первый параметр задан как `int *m[]` , то есть это массив неопределенный длины, элементы которого имеют тип `int *`, то есть массив указателей. 
Из условия задачи очевидно, что это динамически выделенный одномерный массив указателей на одномерные массивы.

Неявно этот параметр преобразуется к типу `int **m`, и представляет собой указатель на первый элемент массива, если действительно в качестве аргумента был передан массив.  Но в виду данного преобразования типа параметра в качестве аргумента можно также передать и указатель типа `int **`.

Данный массив мог быть определен следующим образом:

```
int **m;

m = new int *[rows];

for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
    m[i] = new int [cols];
}

// заполнение массива значениями.

swap_min( m, rows, cols );
```

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void swap_min( int *m[], unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols )
{
    unsigned int min_row = 0, min_col = 0;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i != rows ; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j != cols ; j++ )
        {
            if ( m[i][j] < m[min_row][min_col] )
            {
                min_row = i;
                min_col = j;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( min_row != 0 )
    {
        int *tmp = m[0];
        m[0] = m[min_row];
        m[min_row] = tmp;
    }        
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int rows = 4;
    unsigned int cols = 5;

    int **m = new int *[rows];

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        m[i] = new int[cols];
    }

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++ ) 
        {            
            m[i][j] = std::rand() % ( rows * cols );
        }           
    }        

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++ ) 
        {            
            std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << m[i][j] << ' ';
        }            
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        

    std::cout << std::endl;

    swap_min( m, rows, cols );

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++ ) 
        {            
            std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << m[i][j] << ' ';
        }            
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        delete [] m[i];
    }        

    delete [] m;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
 7  1 11 17 13 
14  0  8  3  2 
 3 14  1  9  9 
 1 12 16 18 12 

14  0  8  3  2 
 7  1 11 17 13 
 3 14  1  9  9 
 1 12 16 18 12
```

Вы также могли воспользоваться стандартными алгоритмами `std::min_element` для поиска минимального элемента в строке и `std::swap` для обмена значениями двух элементов.

Имейте в виду, что на самом деле на вход функции принимается одномерный массив массивов, а не двумерный массив, как у вас сказано в описании.

Для работы с двумерными массивами программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

const unsigned int rows = 4;
const unsigned int cols = 5;

void swap_min( int m[][cols], unsigned int rows )
{
    int tmp[cols];

    unsigned int min_row = 0, min_col = 0;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i != rows ; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j != cols ; j++ )
        {
            if ( m[i][j] < m[min_row][min_col] )
            {
                min_row = i;
                min_col = j;
            }
        }
    }

    //  std::swap( m[0], m[min_row] );
    if ( min_row != 0 )
    {
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < cols; i++ ) tmp[i] = m[0][i];
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < cols; i++ ) m[0][i] = m[min_row][i];
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < cols; i++ ) m[min_row][i] = tmp[i];
    }        
}

int main()
{
    int m[rows][cols];

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++ ) 
        {            
            m[i][j] = std::rand() % ( rows * cols );
        }           
    }        

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++ ) 
        {            
            std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << m[i][j] << ' ';
        }            
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        

    std::cout << std::endl;

    swap_min( m, rows );

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++ ) 
        {            
            std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << m[i][j] << ' ';
        }            
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Ее примерный вывод на консоль

```
12 10 15 14 16 
 7 18  1 16 14 
 9  6  1  9 18 
 4  8 15 11  3 

 7 18  1 16 14 
12 10 15 14 16 
 9  6  1  9 18 
 4  8 15 11  3
```

Опять-таки для обмена двух строк двумерного массива вы могли бы применить стандартный алгоритм `std::swap`, как это указано в комментарии внутри функции.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогло!

Comment: @Александр Дворцов Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Answer (score 4):

`int *m[]` - это массив указателей. Точнее, это указатель на указатель, поскольку в подпрограмму массивы так не передаются.

Вы можете просто поменять местами два указателя - это будет выглядеть как обмен двух строк местами.